# Copy selected files from one folder, retaining the directory structure

Tags: bash, find, copy

I want to copy all the JPG files from one folder to another and it works.

```
find /path/from/dirA/ -name "*.JPG" -exec cp "{}" /path/to/dirB \;
```

To improve on the above, I would like to copy them into the same directory structure with the date. The folder structure is like below without specifying the dates.

```
/path/from/dirB/2022_12_27  to  /path/to/dirB/2022_12_27
/path/from/dirB/2022_12_27  to  /path/to/dirB/2022_12_28
```

How do I go about creating the directory structure in /path/to/dirA, and also retain the file attributes?

Thanks.

Comment: `rsync` is a tool, that can do what you want, locally as well as via a network. You can start by reading some tutorial via the internet, and then use the manual `man rsync` as a dictionary to recall the details ... This is a general example: `sudo rsync -Havn source/ target`; The slash after 'source' is important. It shows a dry run showing what will be done when you remove the option `n`.

Comment: Thanks works well.

Comment: I'm glad that I could help you start using `rsync` :-)

Comment: `rsync` is an immense overkill for this task though, in a sense. What you could also do is something along the lines of `cd /path/from/dirA; tar -c $(find . -name '*.JPG') | (cd /path/to/dirB; tar -x;)`.